# Run multiple Python scripts in Power BI

Tags: python, powerbi, powerquery

I have written a program to carry out a complex calculation with multiple Python scripts that queries multiple database tables. Is it possible to run the main() python script that imports the other Python files from Power BI?

Comment: What is a power bi?

Comment: python does not have `main()`.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can run multiple Python scripts in Power BI to import data into the data model, but there are some considerations:

- each Python script has to result in a separate table
- only pandas data frames are imported
- any script running longer than 30 minutes times out
- there are limitations with respect to third-party packages when running on the Power BI service.

You don't need a "main" script to control the others. They are all executed on a Power BI data refresh request.

For more information, read this:
*[Run Python scripts in Power BI Desktop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-python-scripts)*